# Easy measure theory / integration question

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be a continuous bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$. How do I go about showing that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$ and $\nu$? Further, if $\mu(f) = \nu(f)$ for all such $f$, is it necessarily true that $\mu = \nu$.

Any thoughts on how to procees. I am new to measure theory, so please be gentle.

Comment: What does integrable mean to you? What do you mean by $\mu(f)$, the integral $\int f d \mu$?